# ValueError: shapes (10500,1) and (210,210) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 210 (dim 0)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to practice code from Kaggle in my Jupyter notebook. But I am facing given error below.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
predict_space = np.linspace(min(x),max(x)).reshape(-1,1)
reg.fit(x,y)
Predicted =  reg.predict(predict_space)
```

Error : ValueError: shapes (10500,1) and (210,210) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 210 (dim 0)

Comment: What is x and y and it's shape?

Comment: Problem has been resolved. I have made a mistake on Matrix Dimension. After reshape it has resolved.